# Community guidelines for citation and scientific studies

Tags: discussion

I find this community rather overemphasises the use of scientific studies and has a high requirement for citations. I understand that some fields require that and some people may have been educated in them. I think that's great, a wider range of perspectives and expertise leads to better answers.
However, these people are dominating the conversation on many questions and (as a scientific researcher myself) I find this requirement to be excessive.

Many (otherwise) good answers are down-voted for not providing a source. Studies and citations are requested for common knowledge or scientific consensus widely taught in schools and universities. Studies are frequently asked for in the comments when the question did not request them.

I understand the need to provide citations for new findings or controversial claims but I think this is excessive and hurts our community. Setting the bar so high so referencing material will make it very difficult to grow the community and welcome participation from people not as familiar with academic publications. Experts in the field may also be strapped for time, especially when discussing findings outside of their core research area. If you want good answers from them you'll have to take their word for it. This site for answering specific questions, not resource simply for finding citations in the future.

The purpose of an SE site is to provide these answers. Not to find citations for Psych 101 students. I think this site desperately needs community guidelines on when citations are necessary and when they are not. Does anyone have experience doing this on other sites or any guidelines in mind?

Some suggestions:

1. Reduce the current emphasis to be more welcoming for newcomers
2. Let upvotes (rather than sources) indicate whether an answer is accurate or trustworthy. Reward those that are.
3. The last call is with the OP. If they want sources cited they can ask.

Comment: I agree in general - many issues relevant to the community are not scientific at all, and I'm finding the emphasis on science overbearing at times too (FWIW I teach science subjects and have studied philosophy of science).

Comment: Given [other meta discussion](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/70) about whether references are required, this sort of surprises me. "Many (otherwise) good answers are down-voted for not providing a source" -- can you provide some examples of this?

Comment: See [1](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/109/is-it-safe-to-follow-a-fruitarian-diet-if-not-what-are-the-potential-health-is), [2](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-are-the-main-nutrient-deficiency-concerns-for-vegans/), and [3](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/3/does-a-vegan-diet-actually-cause-weight-loss/). In each of these cases citations are asked for when not required by the OP. I have not encountered this on other SE sites including "Biology" and "Academia".

Comment: Some people seem to view requiring citations as a way to avoid subjective answers or a "flame war". This is absurd: academics still have disagreements (some lasting many years) where they each have supporting evidence in the literature. Articles can be cherry-picked to support almost any opinion.

Comment: I agree, and while I'm not inclined to find and cite examples to support it, it's definitely a feeling I've got from this site.  The choice to be vegan is as much intuitive as intellectual (for me at least), and it sometimes feels as appropriate to back up certain kinds of answer (such as those with a social context) with a reference to a study as it is to ask someone to explain an aspect of religion with a whitepaper.  Just because a URL has .gov on the end doesn't mean it's infallible either.

Comment: I think it matters whether you want to direct people to a source (to discover more of it for themselves) or simply back up claims. If it only serves to say "hey, I'm right", then why not just wait for up votes? Besides, even journal articles can be flawed at times.

Comment: Can you clarify the specifics of this question that aren't a duplicate of: https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/70 -- it feels like a chunk of your question is really (at least the start of) an answer to that

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of this question when posting. I did check for meta questions on scientific studies but their question focused on subjective questions so I missed it. Yes, they are very similar, I think this is all the more support that something needs to be done about this. It is reassuring to see that others feel the same way about it and it appears to be a _vocal minority_ pushing for (arguably unnecessary) citations across the site.

Comment: Specifically, I'm not concerned with what is a good citation (as a PhD researcher I'm well aware of that) but rather when they are needed. The current answer to the other question does not address that but simply recommends them. Common knowledge is debatable (as we've seen on several questions) and rather defeats the purpose of the site. I think this should be left to the discretion of those answering and the OP, rather than being pressured into it, unless there is clearly a serious misinformation issue.